# How to create task in Scrum?

Tags: scrum

We use scrum with our development, we often create task/ticket for developer, and I want to find a way

to record them. But I hava a refused question, that is one way to record them. one way is write on

whiteboards, the other way is write on Agile project management tool(Pivotal Tracker), I think they

are duplicate， so which is better?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends who cares about the tasks.

In teams very new to Scrum, devs can split stories in to tasks to get a better idea of estimates, collaborate on work, etc. For this reason, whatever the devs prefer should be the way forward. Usually a dev will prefer to put tasks on a card, or a whiteboard, or something close to the workspace, but some devs do prefer electronic systems. I find the act of moving a card or writing on a board gives a sense of commitment to a task or story, so I prefer this.

Sometimes the PM prefers to have the tasks so that he can see if a story is 65% done, etc.

Every single time I've seen this it ends up with the PM telling the devs off for not finishing their stories when they said they would, or saying, "It was 85% done yesterday! How can you not have finished it?" This happens a lot with new teams, where devs often prefer to do the easy bits first, or they don't know how to integrate their work with others' yet.

The thing is, there is no value whatsoever in the tasks! It's only possible to get useful feedback by delivering the stories, even if they don't represent completed features but just slices through the system. The tasks themselves are only valuable for the iteration until the stories are completed, so no historic record is needed. PMs who value the tasks often end up with part-done stories and nothing to release or showcase.

For this reason, I would try not to duplicate the tasks for my recording efforts, but just to let the devs make the tasks themselves and put them wherever they want to. It's easy enough to count tasks manually for a burn-down.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to disagree with the previous answer of there not being any value in the tasks. I myself prefer the electronic methods such as:
 - Calenders : Not only do they say what needs to be done but also when and how long it might take
 - Task List : Just like the traditional todo list.
 - Scope Items : Turning the items in the scope spreadsheet into deliverables.

Having physical tasks on cards (tried that) or on the whiteboard in the LLP (did that for a while) is technically better, because you're able to always get to the information quickly. However if your development team is distributed, especially when then PM is in another part of the world, you're going to end up having to duplicate data electronically. The tasks themselves add value to the development house in that they provide good historical data about how long certain tasks take. This information is extremely valuable in building the Scope Matrix of future projects, and as such affect the costing and delivery time. As a side benefit, you'll be able to see by historical trend which asset (i.e. developer) is able to perform and at what efficiency. E.g. If you give a developer a Database task to do and they were inefficient then you'll know next time that database tasks should either be given to someone else or during the down time between projects, said asset should spend time upgrading the database skills.

So important is historical task recording that sometimes clients will ask to see the tasks and how long they took as verification of "the bill". When clients are charged by the development house's hourly rate for work, they want accountability for every hour (or part there of) spent. We used to fill out these sheets with the tasks and the durations to send along with the invoice to the client; and sometimes they would question it.

Comment: People aren't "assets". If you're only looking at helping them learn between projects, instead of encouraging them to learn in order to help out their current project, you may get really slow learning. That's not good in a methodology which is best suited to high uncertainty, high learning projects! You can't Scope Matrix them either. (If your project has no risk, someone already did it - get them to do it again or buy it off the shelf). As for the bill, there are better ways to get the trust of stakeholders - like showcasing - than costing out tasks. Productivity != effectiveness.

Comment: If you are giving developer a task, then you are not using Scrum

Comment: "If you are giving developer a task, then you are not using Scrum" - technically that's true ZloiAdun

Comment: It's not just technically true; it goes against all the principles of an empowered, self-organising team. The team should be able to decide for themselves who does what; nobody should be "giving them" anything other than support and space.

Comment: Not all teams are empowered and self organizing. Only Senior Developers can do that. However handing out tasks is a sure way that works if the team is empowered or not.

Comment: @Kurtnelle, are you a PM? If you could ensure that the team had the skills to be able to succeed - hire the right people, train the others, make it safe to learn the missing bits - then left them to get on with it, what might happen? Have you ever tried this? Does your team merely get work done, or are they collaborators in the business? Can you imagine a different world?

Comment: @kurtnelle: Please don't use "previous answer".  We can sort the answers into any order.  Please **update** your answer to name the specific answer you disagree with.